# redirect https domain root to subfolder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https

I would like to redirect:

"https://  domain.net"

(this page doesn't have an index file, so files are listed - don't know why - no Indexes)

to "https:  //domain.net/en" folder, or "https:  //domain.net/hu"

where there is an index.file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following `.htaccess` rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I added it to the domain.conf (and restart) but still just listing the files of the root folder if I call: https:// domain .net/